# ¿Como filtro una búsqueda Mysql por un tipo de campo?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy con otra duda que no entiendo a Mysql, es un buscador que observa varios campos al buscar, pero necesito que busque con la condicion de que sea solo mirando un tipo de documento, me explico:

| id | nombre | color | mascota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pirulo | marron | perro |
| 2 | keko | gris | perro |
| 3 | roni | blanco | gato |

Supongamos que quiero buscar a pirulo:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="search" name="buscar">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mascotas');
if($_POST){
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre LIKE '%$buscar%' OR color LIKE '%$buscar%' OR mascota LIKE '%buscar%'");
while($campo = mysqi_fetch_array($consulta)){
       echo $campo['nombre'].'<br>';
       echo $campo['color'].'<br>';
       echo $campo['mascota'].'<br>';
}
}
?>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero que pasa si yo quiero buscar solo los perros, lo normal sería que coloque "AND mascota = 'perro'" y con eso bloquee el buscador para los otros animales no? Bueno no me funciona, por favor una ayudita? :)

Comment: que es lo que no te funciona, ya que es solo una consulta de sql, y lo único que veo diferente es que nunca concatenas buscar en mascota , `OR mascota LIKE '%$buscar%'")`, tal vez sea solo error al copiar. pero te falta el indicador de variable $.

Comment: Perdón, si después de mascota le falta el $ a buscar

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es: buscar cualquier elemento de la tabla pero por ejemplo solo de perro así en ese caso solo puede salir: 1, pirulo, marron, perro, 2, keko, gris, perro, y listo, yo después lo ordeno gráficamente pero si yo busco así como está sale todo y está bien, pero yo quiero que solo busque todo de "perro" por eso se me ocurrió: AND mascota = 'perro' al final, pero no funciona, lo qu quiero es bloquear la búsqueda a un tipo de mascota, todo lo que tenga que ver con perro, pero me sale cualquiera hasta gato, no sé como ponerle un bloqueo a todos los LIKE OR que hago

Comment: Lo más sencillo sería separar tablas por cada animal pero eso sería muy de burro, entonces cada consulta se la hago a la tabla correspondiente, pero no creo que sea una función óptima ésa.

Comment: $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre LIKE '%$buscar%' OR color LIKE '%$buscar%' OR mascota LIKE '%$buscar%' AND mascota = 'perro' "); eso no funciona porque no filtra perro.

Comment: No comprendo muy bien en esencia que es lo que debe de realizar el programa, pero te comento que al tener una condición OR le estas indicando que busque por una u otra condición que coincida con el texto, esto a pesar de que integres la condición AND, por esa razón no funciona tu código Por que no lo intentas realizar con el SQL Dinámico formándolo desde PHP? Cuando la búsqueda sea por un campo en especifico formas la condición solo para ese campo. Saludos

Comment: No entiendo bien que es SQL Dinámico, pero desde PHP ya no puedo hacer mucho, si la concidencia ya la hice desde la consulta de mysql obvio en PHP, pero el while ya larga las coincidencias de los OR LIKE y no restringe el AND como un filtro

Comment: Es un buscador de palabras donde solo quiero que busque lo de perro, son dos filas

Comment: Es decir si yo busco "blanco" no tiene que salir nada porque es de gato, estoy intentanto categorizar la búsqueda, es para otro proyecto más grande que tiene otros problemas pero si no resuelvo esto no puedo continuar porque la búsqueda de un tipo de registro es imprescindible

Comment: ya entendí solo añade tu búsqueda normal un () y el adicional mascota, por que lo que haces ahorita es decirle `esta opción o esta o esta o esta y esta`, te tomara todas las que coincidan, si las separas en paréntesis sera `(uno o dos o tres) y cuatro`

Comment: `$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE (nombre LIKE '%$buscar%' OR color LIKE '%$buscar%' OR mascota LIKE '%$buscar%') AND mascota = 'perro' ");`